# How to remove blur subview from super view

Tags: ios, swift, blur

I need to blur screen when alert is shown, so I googled the function, which blurs the screen

it looks like

```
var effectView: UIVisualEffectView!

 func addBlur() {

    var effect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
    effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: effect)
    effectView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)
    view.addSubview(effectView)

}
```

I want to remove the blur after user dismissed the alert and I come up with the such function

```
func removeBlur() {
    effectView.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

but it doesn't work, says UIVisualEffectView does not have a member named "view"

How to fix it?

Comment: I think you just need effectView.removeFromSuperview() here b/c it is a view

Comment: thefredelement is right. It will work.

Comment: Thanks, you are the best! Works great! Maybe u will write it as answer, so I can mark it as solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
func removeBlur() {
    effectView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this way:

```
func blureffect() {
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
}
```